# Sound volume fluctuates randomly

Tags: sound, volume-control

Zoom and in-browser video volume fluctuates randomly without volume sliders changing. Running Ubuntu 22.10. Output of `lspci | grep -i audio` below:

```
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio (rev 21)
```

This is on an HP Spectre x360 laptop from 2018.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Had this same issue with mine and it was only solved by replacing the speaker.